# Turning a 'for'-loop into a 'while'-loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping

I need help with turning a for loop into a while loop, which only prints/logs in differences / changes to an xml.

this is the current code i have thus far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.ruvilla.com/media/sitemaps/sitemap.xml"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for url in soup.find_all("url"):
  titlenode = url.find("loc")
  if titlenode:
  title = titlenode.text
  loc = url.find("loc").text
  lastmod = url.find("lastmod").text
  print title  + "\n" + lastmod
```

Comment: Why do you want to turn it into a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

For your current use case, a for loop works best. However, if you really want to make into a while loop, you can do that like so:

```
urls = soup.find_all("url")
counter = 0
while counter < len(urls)-1:
    counter += 1
    url = urls[counter]
    #Your code here
```

Comment: Now how would i accomplish running it 24/7  and print the newly edited last mod element of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, you are trying to log only the urls which has `lastmod` attribute associated. For this case `for` loop works best instead of `while` because it automatically ends iteration when the end of the list is reached. As in case of while loop you have to explicitly handle with check like `i < len(size)`. You can consider the below:

```
while True:.   # Loop infinitely
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    for url in soup.find_all('url'):
        lastmod = url.find("lastmod").text
        if not lastmod: 
            continue

        loc = url.find("loc").text
        titlenode = url.find("loc")

        if titlenode:
            title = titlenode.text

    time.sleep(1)
```

The `try-except` block is to ensure that the `lastmod` if exists print the details. Else just ignore and go to next URL. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you. But how do i ensure it keeps running and prints the newest changes and not the entire xml?

Comment: You have to probably run the script at the background using crontab in Linux or keep this script running at the background.

Comment: yes i use byobu , however, if i want this iteration to keep runing to find all new changes to the xml, i would have to make it a while loop correct? Thats what im trying to achieve, constantly monitor the sitemap for new changes and print those changes.

Comment: Edited the answer as like a monitor. That will do.You've to explicitly kill the Python process if you want to terminate monitoring

Comment: i keep getting trackback errors. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attmpt.py", line 12, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attmpt.py", line 12, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

Comment: The purpose of SO is to guide users and help them in achieving the task. Not to teach them basics of any specific technology. So I would appreciate you to analyse from here. Thanks